# MOSFET treshold voltage

Tags: mosfet, cmos, physics, physical-design

Does anyone know how MOS treshold voltage varies if the physical distance between source and drain decreases ?

Comment: Threshold voltage is more of a criteria rather than parameter varied by distance between channels. It would be more accurate to assume that oxide thickness would create more of an influence for the threshold voltage by first determining the flatband voltage.

Comment: Is this a Physics question or an EE question, or a mix of both?

Comment: An EE question. All I want is a basic explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the gate length is reduced to the point that it is close to the junction depletion layer width you start to see **short-channel effects**. This is a broad and complex topic...to big to discuss thoroughly on this site, but now you know what term to search for.